# Can't logging in created users in Symfony2 with FOSUserBundle

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I have an application which only admin can create users and I use FOSUserBundle.

I can create user but I've got some problems when I want to login the created user.

They can't login.

I use the default login from FOSUserBundle and it works with users created from command line.

What I missed to do?

This is my createAction from my UserController:

```
public function createAction(Request $request)
{
    $user = new User();

    $form = $this->createForm(new UserType(), $user);

    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($user);
            $em->flush();
        }

        $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('success', 'The user has been added!');
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('crm_users'));
    }

    return $this->render('LanCrmBundle:User:create.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

This is my buildForm:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('username')
        ->add('email')
        ->add('enabled')
        ->add('password')
        ->add('roles', 'choice',  array('choices' => array('ROLE_USER' => 'User', 'ROLE_ADMIN' => 'Admin'),'multiple'  => true));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not encrypting the password while creating the user.

Change the code inside form valid success to,

```
if ($form->isValid()) {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $userManager = $this->container->get('fos_user.user_manager');
    $user->setPlainPassword($user->getPassword());
    $userManager->updatePassword($user);
    $em->persist($user);
    $em->flush();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your default enabled value is false.

Try to set it directly :

```
        if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $user->setEnabled(true);

        $em->persist($user);
        $em->flush();
    }
```

Or put it in your default value in entity class.